# Having only one static instance of a class on startup using NestJS

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I want to initialise a class instance with static attributes, which exists while I run the server. Recreation of the instance is not allowed and the attributes need to be persistent.

Since I've been fairly new to NestJS, I couldn't find any clues in the documentation or examples on how to archive such a thing.

Edit:
[nestjs global pubsub instance and dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104427/nestjs-global-pubsub-instance-and-dependency-injection) unfortunately did not help me to archive the goal.

Comment: I think you're looking for the "singleton pattern" https://medium.com/swlh/node-js-and-singleton-pattern-7b08d11c726a. It's not a NestJS thing, but a general programming pattern.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you very much! I take a look at it.